# Summary of two columns(Weighted Mean)--jqGrid

Tags: php, jqgrid

I need to calculate the weighted mean of two columns i.e.SUM(COL1*COL2)/SUM(COL2) in jqGrid----i'm using jqSuite php by trirand.

I am able to take the two columns and find the sum of its product by

```
    psuedoCOL=>array(col1*col2+>"SUM")
```

psuedoCOL stores the product of the two columns rowwise

I just don't know how to access the sum in psuedoCOL to generate my weighted mean

Comment: First of all you should decide *where* you want to do the calculation: on the server side or on the client side. Moreover you should clear where and when you need to access to the `SUM(COL1*COL2)/SUM(COL2)` values. Do you want to display the values in the next column for example?

Comment: I  want to display the weighted mean at the end of COL1. The calculation will be done on server side. Is this what you meant? I am not quite sure if I understand what you mean. Thanks

Comment: I can't follow you too. You wrote "I want to display ... *at the end* of COL1". Do you mean to display in the same column `COL1`? Why you not just add new column *after* the `COL1`?

Comment: I have more than 1000 entries in my grid. and the weighted average will only be one single value to display in a long column. However, I can put it in a separate column if it helps solve the problem!

Comment: Sorry, but I absolute can't understand what you mean, what you want to display and where. Which relation has 1000 entries? to the problem. Do you use `loadonce: true` option? In any way only one page of data will be displayed. You wrote "the weighted average will only be one single value", but you wrote that you want "to stores the product of the two columns rowwise". What you probably want is to place *single value* somewhere. Where? You can for example use `footerrow: true, userDataOnFooter: true` option and include `userdata` part in the server response.

Comment: Ok so assume col1 has 1000 entries. col2 has 1000 entries. I have another psuedo column that has the product of ith entry of col1 and ith entry of col2 stored at the ith row. At the bottom of psuedo column I have the sum of all the values in the psuedo column. Now I don't know how to use the sum value at bottom of psuedo column to divide the sum of col1. I have not used either footerrow:true or userDataOnFooter:true options

Comment: Is the result which you want to show scalar or the vector (array)? If it's scalar then you can place in server response `userdata: {COL1: "the scalar"}` and use `footerrow: true, userDataOnFooter: true`. jqGrid will place "the scalar" under the column COL1. If it is still not what you want then you should use some simple painting program and show clear where you want place additional information.